# Animated dialog with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to draw a custom(Animation of Image) dialog with AsyncTask. I created a layout with TextView and ImageView to display message and play animation of the images.

Please let me know how can I update the image of the ImageView object to display animation.

Thanks,
Android_IT

Answer (score 0):

Hm, in my project, I show preview of camera like this:

```
ImageView imagePreview = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.previewImage);
imagePreview.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
```